# Image::Magick is gone from Perl CPAN - where is it?

Tags: image, perl, module, imagemagick, cpan

I can't find the Perl module `Image::Magick` anywhere.
It is gone from CPAN.

- What happened to it?
- Where can I get it?
- Is there a problem with CPAN, or with the module?

Comment: Was it ever on cpan? https://imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php

Comment: Closest is probably https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::ImageMagick

Comment: Yes, it was. There are many references to it, and there are other modules which depend upon it and therefore will not install without it. Strange. I installed `Imager` instead...but I still don't think it does everything I need. The actual ImageMagick webpage refers to the `PerlMagick` module, but that links straight back to the metacpan page for `Image::Magick`...which does not exist anymore...

Comment: Will look at `Alien::ImageMagick` as you suggest.

Comment: Alien:: modules usually covers finding/installing libraries. They don't tend to provide an interface to the library.

Comment: @skeetastax - it was gone but seems to be back https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Magick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>My guess is that it's an indexing error on MetaCPAN.</s> - this is wrong, see my update below

You can see various versions of the distribution (which seems to have been renamed from PerlMagick to Image::Magick in 2021) [on CPAN here](https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/J/JC/JCRISTY/).

**Update:** The MetaCPAN advice on [missing modules](https://metacpan.org/about/missing_modules) suggests looking to see if the module is in 02packages.details.txt - which it isn't. So the next step is to contact the author to see if they know anything. Maybe start by [raising a ticket in RT](https://rt.cpan.org//Dist/Display.html?Queue=Image-Magick).

**Update 2:** I started a [conversation about this](https://www.facebook.com/groups/perlcommunity/permalink/1542045793269708/) on the Perl Community FB group, which led to a discussion on #p5p on IRC. We seem to be reaching a consensus that it was some kind of PAUSE error (probably on the upload of the most recent version).

> 14:33 < rjbs> This sounds like some kind of nasty transactionality failure

**Update 3:** Another release seems to have fixed the problem. It's there now:

- https://metacpan.org/release/JCRISTY/Image-Magick-7.1.1-20

Comment: Thx, yes, I took a look at `02packages.details.txt` too and saw it was not there. Ticket is a logical next step.

Answer (score 4):

Old versions can be found on the [BackPAN](http://backpan.perl.org/modules/by-authors/id/J/JC/JCRISTY/). I had to use the Wayback Machine to find the author but at least the distributions were saved!

Answer (score 4):

It was originally released in the PerlMagick distribution, which was then renamed to Image-Magick. Recent uploads haven't included a metadata file (`META.yml` or `META.json`) which is why PAUSE hasn't included it in the CPAN Index. I've [reported this](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/6769) and it will apparently be fixed soon.

#### UPDATE 2023-10-11

The indexing issue has now been fixed. From a quick play with the latest release, it has a number of build issues, so if someone would like to work out what needs fixing on that front and add github issues, I'm sure that would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a new version was recently uploaded here: https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Magick

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I get it?

On Linux you can install from source, i.e. from [GitHub](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick) like this:

```
$ ./configure --with-perl=/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.38.0/bin/perl --prefix=/opt/image-magick
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am running perl on Win11.

Comment: @skeetastax I added a question for Strawberry Perl here: https://github.com/StrawberryPerl/Perl-Dist-Strawberry/issues/138

Answer (score 2):

If in Win11 you have the option to run Perl in [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) (the Ubuntu or perhaps Debian variant) you can still install it with `sudo apt install libimage-magick-perl` there.

Comment: Ah yes, I suppose I could....thx.

Comment: My only question is whether the instance installed under WSL is the same instance as the instance used under Windows...

Comment: @skeetastax: No, it's not. And even if you arranged for your Windows Perl to see the WSL CPAN modules, it wouldn't work because they wouldn't be binary compatible.

Comment: I suspected that may be the case. Ta

Comment: If you so far have used StrawberryPerl or ActivePerl for Windows (or something similar) then WSL will have its own and a different install of Perl. Most probably a different version of Perl too. It needs it's own packages installed. Some pure perl modules could use the same installs I guess by finding and using the right `use lib ...` or setting PERLLIB but I wouldn't do that.